# AR Google Tango Project

Tags: augmented-reality, google-project-tango

I'd like to know how to create a target for architectural large scale AR on a real site.In other words, I need that Google superimposed my 3d model on a specific place.

I have tried Google tango Area Learning tutorials (https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-codelab-area-learning), but after showing the message WALK AROUND TO RELOCALIZE the tablet does nothing, although I walk around to detect the real space, then after few minutes the message Unity project has stopped appears on the Google Tango tablet screen.

Could ADF file used instead of relocalizing the environment?
I've  detected some interior scenes by Tango explorer and saved them,but I'm not able to use them for environment recognition purpose

I work on Unity and Google Tango tablet.

Thank you in advance for your response.﻿

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else facing this problem - the likely cause is not having a recent ADF file already on the device.

You need to first create a Area Description file (ADF) by scanning, and then you can separately Localise to that ADF - so you cannot "use an ADF instead of relocalising."
The tutorial you link above needs you to have separately created an ADF for your location - it simply chooses the most recent one you have.

You can use the [Area Learning example](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/tree/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoSDK/Examples/AreaLearning) to create your ADFs, and try localising to them.  It also shows superimposing 3D models.

Also, look at the augmented reality one to see how to have objects load already in a specific place.